# Prototyping a smart boxing glove: Where to find a "wearable" force sensor that can detect up to 2000 psi

Tags: arduino, sensor, pressure

I am working on prototyping a "smart" boxing glove that can track the movement (jabs, uppercuts etc.) and punch force.

I am having a bit of trouble sourcing a pressure (force) sensor that is small and can detect up to 2000 psi of force.

Is this even possible given the format?

Comment: look at https://www.peratech.com/

Comment: Have you considered the surface area of such a thing?  The ones I've seen used to test punching strength (Mythbusters did this a couple of times) had a fairly large surface area.  A small area would concentrate the force of the blow onto a small area - your sparing partner might be unhappy if you punch him and leave golf ball sized holes every where you hit him.  In the other direction, it'd be kind of tough to throw a punch with the equivalent of a pizza box attached to your glove (though it would probably be hilarious to watch.)

Comment: Yeah, measuring the force on the heavy bag would be relatively easy. Packing this in a boxing glove size is .... complex.

Comment: It would make more sense to measure change in acceleration and velocity on the inside and use a coupling coefficient estimate for the glove compression, target effective force on mass.  Pressure would be impossible to measure without affecting stiffness of surface then use a fluidbag inside glove to model the brain and measure fluid pressure

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 your profile mentions that you are open to contract work, but I could not find any contact info.

Comment: Can you define overall project requirements better?

Comment: @TonyStewart Measuring acceleration and velocity is alright for analysis of a slap. Analysis of a punch NEEDS pressure measurement. Period.

Comment: @Matthew  Question mark.  [I'm genuinely curious.]  Why is pressure required?  Is there a standard set of parameters for punches?

Comment: @Nick. The pressure is required to guage how hard the punch was. If you punch by just moving your arm, it may be quick - but there is little power behind it and any pressure exerted on the target will be brief. If you twist your shoulders and hips whilst punching, the punch will be slightly faster but have much more power behind it and the pressure will be higher and last for longer. Also, imagine a fast punch from a small weak person versus a slower punch from a large strong person - one would hurt more and the other would score higher on a purely velocity/acceleration based measurement.

Comment: Actually velocity and acceleration of impact are both key factors or g and time duration... Pressure is useless as we know a pin has more pressure than car tire but the force of a car will crush you. ALthough I understand pressure is a factor, it is not practical to measure.

Comment: @TonyStewart velocity and acceleration are less relevent than pressure when impacting an unknown load. If you hit a punchbag with an uppercut, a cross or a downward punch with the same force you will get different acceleration (or more accurately deceleration) measurements since the punchbag presents a different dynamic load depending on how you hit it and where you hit it. Integrate the pressure and combine with the velocity to get a realistic measure of the quality of the punch - otherwise you have a slap meter. Go to a boxing gym and get a second opinion.

Comment: i agree but cant think of a suitable sensor other than some sealed fluid bag inside the glove that wont stretch to measure hydraulic pressure

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a smart-watch type thing, packed with accelerometers.

Comment: Sounds like the dumbest of "sports" to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this old abandoned question as off-topic because it was always basically a shopping question, and leaving it open keeps attracting abuse of the answer form with non-answers and link spam.